# Dynamically populate spreadsheet cells with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google spreadsheet that I want to populate with values in an array (array length can vary). I want it to start from cell A5 and go all the way down until the end of the array. Using [SpreadsheetApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)), I am using something like

`sheet.getRange('C4').setValue(name);`

to populate cells. However, I cannot change the cell dynamically in my code so it automatically changes for each value in the array. What's the easiest way to do this?

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276911/google-script-copy-dynamic-range-to-new-spreadsheet) except that my source is not another sheet.

Comment: Why can't you change the cell dynamically? What code are you trying? Shouldn't a basic loop work for you?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `I want to populate with values in an array (array length can vary).`, I cannot understand about the detail of your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And also, from `I am using something like sheet.getRange('C4').setValue(name); to populate cells.`, can you provide your current script?

Comment: I realized I had a different error that was breaking my code and I was able to populate dynamically as expected.